# Get type of a class and instantiate another instance of it

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

### Question

I have a base class `Number` that is inherited by classes `One`, `Two` and `Three`.

I have a property

```
public Number SomeNumber{get;set;}
```

Initially, I have set `SomeNumber` to either `One`, `Two` or `Three` (Value Generated Randomly).

Later on, I want to set `SomeNumber` to a new class of the same type of the old class. Is this possible? If so, how?

### Example:

On initialization, `SomeNumber` is set to `One`

Later on in the program, I want to set `SomeNumber` to a new instance of `One`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would add an abstract Method CreateInstance on the Number and implement it in all its concrete subclasses.

```
abstract class Number
{
  abstract Number CreateInstance();
}

class One : Number
{
  override Number CreateInstance()
  {
    return new One();
  }
}
```

"later on"

```
Number newNumber = SomeNumber.CreateInstance();
```

It doesn't need reflection, is therefore typesafe and it would support arguments if the constructors would need some.

Comment: Never thought of using abstract classes. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Number has to be an abstract class for it to have an abstract member

Comment: You *could* make it just virtual. This concept doesn't depend on this. It depends if you need instances which are just `Number`, or if they actually do not exist.

Answer (score 1):

```
SomeNumber = (Number)Activator.CreateInstance(SomeNumber.GetType());
```

For parameters, you must box up the parameters as such:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Number SomeNumber { get; set; }
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        SomeNumber = new One();

        SomeNumber = (Number)Activator.CreateInstance(SomeNumber.GetType(), new[] {1});
    }

}

public class Number
{

}

public class One : Number
{
    public One()
    {

    }
    public One(Object a)
    {

    }

}
```

The post above by Stefan is a better method of implementing it.
Another option would be to create an object factory

Comment: What if the class (Number) has a constructor with parameters